# Update location data after enabling GPS

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm trying to do an app that detects if the GPS is enable or not. If not, the app should have to update the location data with data received when the GPS is enabled, but right now I'm not able to do this way. My code is the following:

```
public class App extends Activity implements LocationListener {
private GoogleMap googleMap;
protected TextView city;
protected TextView street;
LocationManager lm = null;
LocationListener ll = null; 
Location location;
Boolean isGPSEnabled;
Boolean isNetworkEnabled;
Boolean canGetLocation;
double longitude;
double latitude;
public static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters
public static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000*60*1; // 1 minute

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_parking_coche);

    boolean flag = displayGpsStatus();

    if (flag){
        initilizeMap();

        lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 

        location = getLocation();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();

        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        String ciudad="",calle="";
        try{
            geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

            calle = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            ciudad = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }


        city = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCiudad);
        street = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCalle);
        city.setText(ciudad);
        street.setText(calle);


        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car_map_35_35));

        // adding marker
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(17).build();

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
    else
    {
        alertbox("Estado GPS", "Su GPS está desactivado");
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    boolean flag = displayGpsStatus();

    if (flag){

        initilizeMap();

        lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
        location = getLocation();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        String ciudad="",calle="";
        try{
            geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

            calle = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            ciudad = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }


        city = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCiudad);
        street = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCalle);
        city.setText(ciudad);
        street.setText(calle);


        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car_map_35_35));

        // adding marker
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(17).build();

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
    else
    {
        alertbox("Estado GPS", "Su GPS está desactivado");
    }
}

protected void alertbox(String title, String mymessage) {  
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
  builder.setMessage(mymessage)  
  .setCancelable(false)  
  .setTitle(title)  
  .setPositiveButton("Habilitar GPS",  
   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);  
        startActivity(myIntent);  
        dialog.cancel();  
   }  
   })  
   .setNegativeButton("Cancelar",  
   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  
    // cancel the dialog box  
    dialog.cancel();  
    }  
   });  
  AlertDialog alert = builder.create();  
  alert.show();  
 } 

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        lm = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = lm
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = lm
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network Enabled");
                if (lm != null) {
                    location = lm
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (lm != null) {
                        location = lm
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No se ha podido mostrar el mapa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ll = new App();
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, ll, null);
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.removeUpdates(ll); 
    lm = null;
  }
```

Right now if the GPS is disabled and then I enabled it the data displayed is nothing. How I can achieve that the data would be updated after the GPS is enabled?

Thank you in advanced.

Code updated after putting the same code of onCreate method in onResume method:

> 10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.axiomapps.app/com.axiomapps.app.app}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2919)
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2948)
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358)
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    at com.axiomapps.app.App.onResume(App.java:249)
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1209)
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5450)
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)
>   10-27 10:08:16.578: E/AndroidRuntime(30986):    ... 10 more

Comment: you go somewhere else from your project for turning the GPS on, when you come back you just check long and lat again in `onResume` of your activity.

Comment: all you have to do is move the code that retrieves the coordination from `onCreate` to `onResume`

Comment: DroidDev, when I enable the GPS I come back to the same activity before enabling GPS.

Comment: then run a service in background that'll keep checking the GPS status and will tell you when it is turned on. Stop the service when GPS is turned on, but start it again when it is stopped and you need to check for its status. Its just a hack. I don't know if there is a better way to do it, but I'd do it this way :D

Comment: @Coderji, when I put that code in onResume method I get an error (I put in my updated post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create new object of your activity, it's wrong. You can't do like that:

```
ll = new App(); // you created new instance of your activity, you can't do that
lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, ll, null);
```

It must do like this:

```
lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null); //replaced to "this"
```